# Shut down a computer once a specific group of processes are completed

Tags: linux, bash, google-cloud-platform

I was wondering if there any way I can shut down a computer (or VM on google cloud platform) once a group of processes are all completed in command line (bash)

For example:
I have five jobs running: Job_1, ..., Job_5. Each job might complete at different time, and I would like to shut down the computer once all jobs are completed.

===============Some update===============

The commands that I used just submit the works, and they finished immediately, the works will become multiple processes and running on the back. In this case, should I shutdown the computer based on the status of the processes?

Answer (score 2):

Since there is a command to shut down a computer, it's very simple:

```
{ job1; job2; job3; job4; job5; }; shutdown -h now
```

I put jobs 1 through 5 inside a command group only to show that you can run arbitrary shell commands as a single group, and when that completes, `shutdown` will run. Inside the command group, you don't have to run the 5 jobs sequentially; you can run some or all of them in parallel, and use the `wait` built-in command to prevent the command group from exiting until all 5 jobs are complete.